# Instrumentation: Measurement Noise

Tags: oscilloscope, instrumentation, precision, accuracy

I have a Tektronix DPO2014 and I'm trying to get a feel for what I can expect in terms of precision and accuracy performance on a clean and stable voltage. I'd like to be able to accurately and precision measure voltages in the 0 - 20mV range with a precision of 1 mV, just to throw in use some concrete numbers.

So I hooked up five fresh AA batteries, connected the GND clip of the channel 1 probe to the ground of the battery pack, and connected the witch's hat clip of channel 1 to the positive terminal of the battery pack. I set up the scope to display Measured values of Min, Max, and Mean and what it tells me is: Min = 7.96V, Max = 8.2V Mean = 8.09V - 8.11V (watching it over time).

I presumed a battery pack would be a very clean and very resilient (to noise) DC source. So how might I figure out what this apparent +100mV / -140mV of noise riding on my measurement is coming from? Even if I turn on Averaging (8 samples) in the Acquire menu, I see a span of 8.072V - 8.124V for the min / max span, and the mean becomes 8.109V to 8.112V (so more like 25-30mV of deviation from the mean).

If I switch channel 1 to AC coupled mode and use 64 sample averaging on Acquire, I see min/max values of about -1.8mV to +7.2mV. Can anyone think of what, if anything, I might be doing wrong? Or is the performance of my oscilloscope just not capable of accurately and precision measuring signals in the sub 10mV range?

Answer (score 2):

Try the x1 probe setting and 20MHz BW limit and AC-coupled and you should see an improvement.

Remember, an oscilloscope will have a very high sample rate (1GS/s) but quite coarse voltage resolution- in the case of your 'scope, only 8 bits vertical resolution (1 part in 256).

If you want to see precision slow-moving signals you need something more optimized for that application such as a data acquisition system or a voltmeter.

Comment: yea, my Fluke 115 multimeter seemingly does a better job at this frankly. My mind was wandering into the realm of is that because my multimeter isn't plugged into the wall.

Answer (score 2):

The scope's only 8bit (most of them are), at 8V, that means your LSB is 8/256 or ~30mV so the 20-30mV noise you're seeing is perfectly normal. The noise is more related to your full scale range more than anything else, as a rule of thumb for an 8bit scope, assume 1LSB of noise which works out to full scale range/256. E.g. with a 100V FSR expect ~0.4V noise, at 5V FSR expect 20mV noise and at 200mV FSR expect ~1mV noise (at such low full scale ranges, noise from other places starts to have a noticeable effect)

Now, when you turn on averaging it takes several samples and averages them together, because most noise is non-additive, averaging several samples smooths out the noise and is a good way to get a couple extra bits or resolution at the expense of apparent sample rate (I think the math was 4x oversampling per bit or something).

It hasn't got much to do with your scope being plugged in, just about every ADC in existence as some jitter (which gets worse at higher sample rates) so noise on the order of 1 LSB is not uncommon. Now your fluke on the other hand will have a really really low sample rate (or lots of averaging or both) which is why it gives more stable voltage readings, but people don't really use scopes as voltmeters. Scopes are for looking at shapes, voltmeters are for looking at numbers.

(N.B. the small loop formed by the ground lead acts like an AM antenna loop, so you will pick up some radio noise as well)